# Why does Console.Read() not give the value I expect for integer input?

Tags: c#

For some reason, the VSE C# 2010 (or maybe the problem is in my laptop) is not interpreting the <, >, <= and >= Boolean comparison operators correctly.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter an integer:");
        int myInt = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
        bool isLessThan10 = myInt < 10;
        bool isBetween0and5 = (0 <= myInt) && (myInt <= 5);
        Console.WriteLine("Integer less than 10? {0}", isLessThan10);
        Console.WriteLine("Integer between 0 and 5? {0}", isBetween0and5);
        Console.WriteLine("Exactly one of the above is true? {0}",
            isLessThan10 ^ isBetween0and5);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

---

```
Enter an integer:
2
Integer less than 10? False
Integer between 0 and 5? False
Exactly one of the above is true? False
```

Comment: Step through this in the debugger and see what the value of myInt actually is. I bet it's not what you expect.

Comment: If you're gonna claim that there's a bug in VS, you better show us everything you've done to be sure :P It's much more likely there's something wrong with your code.

Comment: Thank you, dodexahedron and eddie_cat. You are right eddie_cat: Servy's answer help me find my now-GLARING mistake: Console.ReadLine.

Answer (score 7):

`Console.Read` reads in a single character and returns the ASCII value of that character.  The ASCII value of the character `2` is not `2`.

You want to read in the character and get it's representation *as a character*, which you can do through the use of `Console.ReadKey` (as you do later in your program) or `Console.ReadLine` if you want to read a string of characters interpreted as such, rather than using `Console.Read`.  You can then convert that string representation of a number into it's numeric representation using `int.Parse`.

Comment: Or `Console.ReadLine` to be able to input multi-digit numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much Servy and Lasse V. Karlsen! Problem fixed! I'm so embarrassed by that very stupid mistake!